# ssh -X to connect with remote client

Tags: xorg, fonts, remote-desktop, remote, remote-login

I try to use "ssh -X -p port username@ip_address" to login remote client.As you can see,I can use my local screen to open remote GNU application because of "-X".
Unfortunately I find the size of remote graphical interface is too small to see.Is there any method to solve remote x-display font small.Thank you.

Comment: I know a method，which is change local screen resolution to lower. But I don't really like this approach. ,Maybe I can larger fonts size of remote computer.

Comment: did you solve this?